# Anyone get mach_inject working on snow leopard?

Tags: macos, hook, code-injection

Project is now on github and here is the link to my [issue](http://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star/issues#issue/1)

I successfully compiled the whole thing and able to run rejector and rejectee separately.
But the injector will crash the injectee when injecting code to the target process.

```
mach_inject_test_injectee.app 's standard output:
mach error on bundle load (os/kern) successful
mach error on bundle load (os/kern) successful
mach error on bundle load (os/kern) successful
mach error on bundle load (os/kern) successful
mach error on bundle load (os/kern) successful
FS rep     /Users/Malic/Documents/Code/c/mach_star/mach_inject_test/build/Development/mach_inject_test_injector.app/Contents/Resources/mach_inject_test_injected.bundle/Contents/MacOS/mach_inject_test_injected
LOADDDDDDDDDD!
Assertion failed: (0), function +[injected_PrincipalClass load], file     /Users/Malic/Documents/Code/c/mach_star/mach_inject_test/injected-PrincipalClass.m, line    25.
Abort trap
```

mach_inject_test_injector 's standard output

```
injecting into pid 3680
injecting pid
mach_inject failing.. (os/kern) successful
mach inject done? 0
hi
```

It seems from the output the injector is not notified from the injectee, any ideas? thanks.

Comment: I had a same problem. I tried sudo chgrp procmod /path/to/executable
sudo chmod 2755 /path/to/executable, but its not working for me.

Comment: I get this error and Injector crash
`You probably need to add user to procmod group, mach_inject failing.. (ipc/send) invalid destination port`

If I run injector as root user, injectee crashes.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star/issues/23) should help you out, it looks like a patched version exists in the [simbl tree.](https://github.com/albertz/simbl) The caveat being you can only inject into an app of similar bit depth (32 or 64).

Answer (score 0):

I had some issue, Compiling for x86 with "-arch i386" helped me, I wasn't able to make it works for x86_64.

Hope it helps.